# TextView like instagramm comments on Android

Tags: android, textview

How to make text look like instagramm comments, with ckickable nick with one color and not clickable text with another color and optional clickable text tags.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try [this tutorial](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring)